# Wrapping Text on image in jimp not working

Tags: node.js, image-processing

I'm trying to write text to an image and wrap the text as well with jimp, but currently the text overflows on a single line off the image. I'm following the docs but mine just doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
let image = {};
        return Jimp.read('app/background.png')
        .then(imageResponse => {
            // Image is 500 x 500
            image = imageResponse
            return Jimp.loadFont(Jimp.FONT_SANS_64_BLACK);
        })
        .then(font => {
            return image.print(font, margin, margin, 'Very Long Hello WOrld Text', 200)
        })
        .then(image => {
            return image.writeAsync(`app/new-${(new Date()/1000)}.png`);
        })
```

Comment: Did you read the [Jimp doc section about staggering text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp#staggering-text)?

Comment: Yes. The stagger text is if you plan on adding text just below or relative to the previous text. My issue here is as relates with Wrapping just one single text after it reaches the max width specified.

Comment: Your code above worked perfectly for me, when adding a short text watermark to an image. Thanks for posting :)

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to answer this, But I came up with my own logic to wrap text inside JIMP image.

Below code will create an array of strings having length less than allowed limit.

So we can change the limit as per our image width.

```
let message = "Some very large text which will not fit in one line, lets try fitting this in multiple lines";
let x = 10;
let y = 10;

let stringArr = message.split(' ');

let finalArr = [];
let strLengthBefore = 0, strLengthAfter = 0;
let limitLength = 30;
let tempStr = '';

for (let i = 0; i < stringArr.length; i++) {
    strLengthAfter = strLengthBefore + stringArr[i].length + 1;
    if (strLengthAfter >= limitLength) {
        finalArr.push(tempStr);
        tempStr = '';
        strLengthBefore = 0, strLengthAfter = 0;
        i = i - 1;
    } else {
        tempStr += stringArr[i] + ' ';
        strLengthBefore += stringArr[i].length;
        if (i == stringArr.length - 1) {
            finalArr.push(tempStr);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now just loop over the array and print text on image.

```
 let font = await Jimp.loadFont(path.join(base_path, 'montserrat_bold_italic.fnt'));
    y = 200;
    for (let i = 0; i < finalArr.length; i++) {
        image.print(font,
            10,
            y,
            {
                text: finalArr[i],
                alignmentX: Jimp.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER,
                // alignmentY: Jimp.VERTICAL_ALIGN_MIDDLE
            },
            560,
            800
        );
        y += 30;
    }
```

Hope this would help.